# UIWindow? does not have member named bounds

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to update PKHUD (https://github.com/pkluz/PKHUD) to work with Xcode 6 beta 5 and am almost through except for one tiny detail:

```
internal class Window: UIWindow {
    required internal init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    internal let frameView: FrameView
    internal init(frameView: FrameView = FrameView()) {
        self.frameView = frameView

        // this is the line that bombs
        super.init(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window!.bounds)

        rootViewController = WindowRootViewController()
        windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal + 1.0
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        addSubview(backgroundView)
        addSubview(frameView)
    }
    // more code here
}
```

Xcode gives me the error `UIWindow? does not have a member named 'bounds'`. 
I'm pretty sure this is a trivial mistake related to type-casting, but I've been unable to find the answer to this for a couple hours.

Also, this error occurs only in Xcode 6 beta 5, which means that the answer lies in something Apple changed recently.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration of the `window` property in the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol
changed from

```
optional var window: UIWindow! { get set } // beta 4
```

to

```
optional var window: UIWindow? { get set } // beta 5
```

which means that it is an optional property yielding an optional `UIWindow`:

```
println(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window)
// Optional(Optional(<UIWindow: 0x7f9a71717fd0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); ... >))
```

So you have to unwrap it twice:

```
let bounds = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window!!.bounds
```

or, if you want to check for the possibility that the application delegate has
no window property, or it is set to `nil`:

```
if let bounds = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window??.bounds {

} else {
    // report error
}
```

**Update:** With Xcode 6.3, the `delegate` property is now also
defined as an optional, so the code would now be

```
let bounds = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!.bounds
```

or

```
if let bounds = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.bounds {

} else {
    // report error
}
```

See also [Why is main window of type double optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901893/why-is-main-window-of-type-double-optional) for more solutions.

Comment: Hi, do you know why changed from var window: UIWindow! to var window: UIWindow? ? I feel that doesn't make sense.