# Why is main window of type double optional?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, uiwindow

When accessing `UIapplication's` main window it is returned as a `UIWindow??`

```
let view = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window // view:UIWindow??
```

Why is it returning as a double optional and what does it mean and if put into a `if let` should I add one `!` after it?

```
if let view = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!
```

My first though was to replace `?` with a `!` after delegate but that was not the solution.

Comment: It's not: `optional var window: UIWindow? { get set }` – your `delegate` is optional-chained though (using `?`), which results in another level of optionals.

Comment: But even when i put ! to the right of delegate instead, it still gives ??

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175544/uiwindow-does-not-have-member-named-bounds.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR in if let I added ?? at the end of the line and now it makes view non optional inside the curly braces.

Comment: One `?` for optional delegate variable implementation, and another `?` for variable of optional type.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

@matt has the details, but there is a (somewhat horrible, somewhat awesome) workaround. (See edit below, though)

```
let window = app.delegate?.window??.`self`()
```

I will leave the understanding of this line of code as an exercise for the reader.

OK, I lie, let's break it down.

```
app.delegate?.window
```

OK, so far so good. At this point we have the `UIWindow??` that is giving us a headache (and I believe is a <strike>bug in Swift</strike> disconnect between Swift and Cocoa). We want to collapse it twice. We can do that with optional chaining (`?.`), but that unwraps and rewraps, so we're back where we started from. You can double-optional-chain, though, with `??.` which is bizarre, but works.

That's great, but `??` isn't a legal suffix operator. You have to actually chain to something. Well, we want to chain back to itself (i.e. "identity"). The `NSObject` protocol gives us an identity method: `self`.

`self` is a method on `NSObject`, but it's also a reserved word in Swift, so the syntax for it is `` `self`() ``

And so we get our madness above. Do with it as you will.

Note that since `??.` works, you don't technically need this. You can just accept that `view` is `UIWindow??` and use `??.` on it like `view??.frame`. It's a little noisy, but probably doesn't create any real problems for the few places it should be needed.

(*) I used to think of this as a bug in Swift, but it's not fixable directly by optional chaining. The problem is that there is no optional chaining past `window`. So I'm not sure where the right place to fix it is. Swift could allow a postfix-`?` to mean "flatten" without requiring chaining, but that feels odd. I guess the right operator would be interrobang `delegate?.window‽` :D I'm sure that wouldn't cause any confusion.

EDIT:

[Joseph Lord pointed out the better solution](https://twitter.com/jl_hfl/status/573880245578776577) (which is very similar to techniques I've been using to avoid trivial if-let, but hadn't thought of this way before):

```
let window = app.delegate?.window ?? nil // UIWindow?
```

I agree with him that this is the right answer.

Comment: well, `?.` is `flatMap`, so I'm not sure it fixes it.

Comment: But still, that doesn't compile (Swift 1.1) in a Playground. Probably because it doesn't know if it should return an `UIWindow??` or an `UIWindow?` (both would be valid)

Comment: And if you don't want optional: `let window = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window ?? nil)! as UIWindow
`

Answer (score 19):

It's because the `window` property is itself in doubt (it's optional). Thus, you need one question mark because there might or might not be a window property, and another question mark because the return value of that window property is itself an Optional. Thus we get a double-wrapped Optional (as I explain in my [tutorial](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionalProtocol): scroll down to the Tip box where I talk about what happens when an optional property has an Optional value).

Thus, one way to express this would be in two stages — one to cast (and unwrap *that* Optional), and one to fetch the window (and unwrap *that* Optional):

```
if let del = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
    if let view = del.window {
```

Now `view` is a UIWindow.

Of course, if you're sure of your ground (which you probably are), you can force the cast in the first line and the unwrapping in the second line. So, in Swift 1.2:

```
let del = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let view = del.window!
```

Comment: At least in 6.3, `delegate` is of type `UIApplicationDelegate?`. Optional chaining should get rid of that extra layer of optional.

Comment: @RobNapier Re-expressed. - I've _never_ liked this particular double optional. Swift goes a little far here, in my view.

Comment: Agreed. But it would be fixed if optional-chaining supported objc-protocol-optional (which I consider a bug that it does not).

Comment: @RobNapier Agreed (with your bug).

Comment: Note in 1.2, you can also use multi-if-let rather than force-unwrapping (or nested if-let). I just always hate to use `!` unless it dramatically improves things.

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, I know about the 1.2 syntax. I'm not convinced that it's better, though. All it does for you, really, is prevent a bunch of right-curly-braces at the end. I prefer the "pyramid of doom"... But the OP can see my discussion [here](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_conditional_binding) if he's curious.

Answer (score 2):

Oh the double optional! Sometimes you can use a double-bang (two exclamation marks) but you cannot cast that way with optional binding. So... my remix of all the other code gets you a UIWindow object called `window` of the non-optional kind:

```
guard let w = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window, let window = w else { return }
```

But let's not waste time and just use

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!
```

and be done.

Answer (score 0):

With advent of Swift2 for me a usual workaround in this kind of cases is

```
if let _window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window, window = _window {
    // Some code... i.e.
    let frame = window.frame
}
```