# How to detect iOS app in split view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to add some logic when iOS app is going to start split view mode or step over, and also resign that mode? Is there any notification or delegate method to detect this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your window occupies the whole screen:

```
BOOL isRunningInFullScreen = CGRectEqualToRect([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.frame, [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.screen.bounds);
```

If false = split view or a slide over.

[Check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33371476/1187415)

Comment: Perhaps it is pure chance that your answer is identical to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33371476/1187415 (including the unnecessary semicolon). But *if* you copy code from another answer then you must add a link to the original for proper attribution, otherwise it is considered plagiarism.

Answer (score -2):

if you use standard navigation functions you can check

```
if (self.splitViewController != nil){...}
```

in viewDidLoad method

Comment: By split view I think he means iPad multitasking

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. I mean multitasking not UISplitViewController

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand it from your description