# Identify app in Split view Mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, splitview

I want to identify whether my app is in split view mode (latest iPad feature in iPad Air 2). Is there any way programatically I can determine that or any delegate methods that are called when app goes to split view mode and back to full view ?

The issue I am facing now is when i push a table view controller onto the master table view in iPad in  Split view (i.e. when two apps are in a split view mode in the latest iPad Air 2). Then after if I make that app in full screen mode the table view gets jumbled up and shows in the detail section of the Master detail view whereas it was supposed to be on the top of Master table view. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if app is running in Slide Over or Split View mode in iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367387/detect-if-app-is-running-in-slide-over-or-split-view-mode-in-ios-9)

Comment: When the apps are in split view mode and if i push a UITableViewController onto the Master table view it shows the new table view controller in the split mode. But when i make that app primary by dragging the split mode the newly pushed TableviewController comes in the detail section (the test is done with iPad in landscape mode). Since there are no delegate methods to notify when app changes from split mode to original full view mode, how to handle that issue ?

Comment: @subin272 did you find anything to help you with this?

Comment: I assume this will help!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442761/how-to-detect-if-another-app-is-running-as-slide-over-in-ios-11