# How can I use ARKit while using Slide Over/Split Screen on iPadOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, arkit, ipados

I have an app that uses ARKit to detect faces and send over the network the coordinates of interest, which works well. I would like this app to run in background, still sending the data over the network, while I would be using another app (almost) fullscreen.

The option 'Enable multiple windows' is activated in info.plist, but as soon as I launch my other app, the ARKit app stops sending information (the app actually probably stops).

Is there a simple way to do this, and at least is this feasible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at this point. Camera and AR stuff is disabled at a system level in apps when they are displayed in Slide Over or Split View.

I'd recommend displaying a warning message when Slide Over/Split Screen is being used saying that you should use the app in full screen mode. [See this answer under a different question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620972/3151675).