# Different UI depending on whether app is full screen or split screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ipados

I wan to create different ui depending on whether app is full screen or split screen just like the Vectornator app in SwiftUI. How do i do this?
[image: Full screen view of vectornator]
[image: Split screen view of vectornator]

Comment: Check out Size classes

Comment: @aheze Thank you so much. It solved my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if app is running in Slide Over or Split View mode in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367387/detect-if-app-is-running-in-slide-over-or-split-view-mode-in-ios-9)