# Unwrap a double optional (Type??) with if let syntax in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

If I attempt to compile the following code, it will fail on the `print` line.

```
func foo(application: UIApplication) {
    if let window = application.delegate?.window {
        print(window.frame) // SYNTAX ERROR
    }
}
```

The reason is that window is of type `UIWindow?`, not `UIWindow`:

> error: value of optional type 'UIWindow?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

I can fix it by doing this:

```
func foo(application: UIApplication) {
    if let window = application.delegate?.window {
        if let window = window {
            print(window.frame)
        }
    }
}
```

However, that adds more lines of code, and it seems like it shouldn't be necessary. I thought the `if let <variable> = <value>` was supposed to only execute its body if `window` was found to be non `nil`.

In other words, I was hoping it would use this kind of logic:

- If `application.delegate = nil`, don't execute the block.
- If `application.delegate.window = nil`, don't execute the block.
- If `application.delegate.window != nil`, execute the block and allow me to use `window` as a non-optional `UIWindow`.

Why is `if let window = application.delegate?.window` defining `window` as an optional? Is there any way I can get it to behave like the second snippet above by adding little or no code?

Note: I do not want to use `print(window?.frame)` because printing is only an example. I actually have much more code and don't want to use the null object pattern. I want it to *really* be defined as a non-optional.

**Update**: If I use `let test = application.delegate?.window`, I see that the type is `UIWindow??`, or a double optional. This explains why I do need the second let statement. So I guess my question is now what is the most concise way to unwrap a double optional?

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901893/why-is-main-window-of-type-double-optional.

Comment: your mistake is that `Optional.None` (nil) is different from `Optional.Some(Optional.None)` (not nil).  Which is like saying a missing box is different from a box that doesn't have second, expected box inside it.

Answer (score 4):

one possible solution...

```
if let window = application.delegate?.window ?? nil {
  print(window.frame)
}
```

Comment: @MrsEd why it's not an answer?

Comment: @MrsEd I do not see the point either...

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site not a forum.  So it's better to phrase answers as *answers* rather than questions.    Apart from anything else it may confuse casual (re)viewers.

Comment: ok. thx for the clarification. edited the answer to make clear that it **is** actually an answer... :)