# Swift ?? on a type

Tags: swift

I know what the ?? is when used as an operator but what does it mean when it is on a Type?

I have a struct in my project called `MyStruct` and the autocompletion of a particular var tells me it is of type `MyStruct??`

Not really sure what that means or how to unwrap it safely.

Comment: It is `Optional<Optional<MyStruct>>`, a "optional optional MyStruct".

Comment: Nested optionals: `Optional(Optional(value))`. Unwrap twice.

Comment: Typical example `UIApplicationDelegate.window`, an optional property that can contain an optional. Or indexing an optional dictionary.

Comment: Safely unwrap: `var myStruct: MyStruct?? = MyStruct()`
        `if let middleOpt = myStruct, myStruct = middleOpt{}`

Comment: Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901893/why-is-main-window-of-type-double-optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, it's a double Optional, completely unrelated to the nil coalescence operator (`??`).

To unwrap it, you just unwrap a regular optional, twice:

```
let doubleOptional: MyStruct?? = MyStruct()

guard let singleOptional = doubleOptional else {
    //first unwrapping failed
}

guard let wrappedValue = singleOptional else {
    //second unwrapping failed
}

//use wrappedValue
```

These are quite uncommon, but there are times when they're useful.

For example, consider you have a data structure that stores an average of an array. The array might be empty, thus the average should be allowed to be `nil`, to indicate there is no average. Suppose calculating this average is very expensive and we want to store it in a caching layer. This caching layer could have a double optional representing that average. If the value is `Optional.None` (i.e. `nil`), we know the cache doesn't have a value yet, thus it needs to be computed. If the value is `Optional.Some(Optional.None)`, we know the cache has a value, but that there is no valid average (i.e. the array was empty. Lastly, the value could be `Optional.Some(Optional.Some(/*...*/))`, which represents a valid cache value of a valid average.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense when you think about it. I have a task which may return an error or may return a result. That result may have some value or may be nil. So the result is ??. Sorted now anyway. Thanks

Comment: It's part of a networking framework. The errors are server errors returned to a completion block. Would do otherwise.