# What does ?? mean on a variable declaration in Swift case let pattern matching?

Tags: ios, swift, variable-assignment

I am reviewing some pull requests internally, and see a pattern matching statement like this:

```
if case let presentationAnchor?? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window,
```

Now I understand `??` is a nil coalescing operator when used on the other side of the `=`, e.g. `aString ?? "default value"`, but what is it when it's used on the left hand side of the `=` assignment? Is it some way to unwrap an optional when assigning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of pattern matching, `x?` is the “optional pattern” and equivalent to `.some(x)`. Consequently, `case x??` is a “double optional pattern” and equivalent to `.some(.some(x))`.

It is used here because `UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window` evaluates to a “double optional” `UIWindow??`, compare [Why is main window of type double optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901893/why-is-main-window-of-type-double-optional).

Therefore

```
if case let presentationAnchor?? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window
```

matches the case that `UIApplication.shared.delegate` is not nil *and* the delegate implements the (optional) `window` property. In that case `presentationAnchor` is bound to the “doubly unwrapped” `UIWindow`.

See also [Optional Pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID520) in the Swift reference:

> An optional pattern matches values wrapped in a `some(Wrapped)` case of an `Optional<Wrapped>` enumeration. Optional patterns consist of an identifier pattern followed immediately by a question mark and appear in the same places as enumeration case patterns.

Comment: "matches the case that UIApplication.shared.delegate is not nil" I think you meant to say it matches the case that the app delegate doesn't even implement the `window` property, since it's an [optional Objective-C property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623056-window).

Comment: Optional properties in an Objective-c protocol are optionals in Swift (and nil if the property is not implemented) so that is essentially the same. But you are right, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

```swift
if case let someVar? = anotherVar
```

is sugar syntax for

```swift
if case let .some(someVar) = anotherVar
```

Adding another question mark expands to a double optional, equivalent to

```swift
if case let .some(.some(someVar)) = anotherVar
```

Two question marks on the left side of the pattern match means the `if` will be executed if the double optional holds a non-nil value at both levels.