# Why does Swift 5 optional chaining for safeAreaInserts require two question marks in window??.safeAreaInsets instead of one question mark?

Tags: swift, optional-chaining

The Swift compiler complains about

`let insets : UIEdgeInsets? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window?.safeAreaInsets`

with the error message

`Value of optional type UIWindow? must be unwrapped to refer to member safeAreaInsets of wrapped base type UIWIndow.  Chain the optional using '?' to access member safeAreaInsets only for non-nil base values.`

The code

`let insets : UIEdgeInsets? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets`

works fine.  Why is the second question mark after `window` required?  The two question marks here do not seem to constitute the nil-coalescing operator.  I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why is main window of type double optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901893/why-is-main-window-of-type-double-optional)