# why does UIWindow has two question marks (UIWindow??)

Tags: ios, swift

UIWindow is declared with 2 question marks --> UIWindow?? (at least autocompletion says so)
What does this mean? I'm pretty sure it's not nil coalescing operator.

Maybe that is a poor choice of words... The window property of appDelegate is of type UIWindow??.

Comment: is this a Swift question? Update your tags.

Comment: I just looked in one of my client's apps and the app delegate's property is defined a optional UIWindow (`UIWindow?`) just like you'd expect. I'm not seeing a double question mark as you mention.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25176521/1187415.