# Why make window property in the UIApplicationDelegate optional instead of implicitly unwrapped optional?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, uiwindow

Why `var window: UIWindow?` not `UIWindow!`, i.e. why making window optional, isn't each app should have a main UIWindow (without it the app can't function at all) ?!

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175544/uiwindow-does-not-have-member-named-bounds) said it did indeed change from `UIWindow!` to `UIWindow?` so it must have a reason. I just can't figure out why. Also, with `UIWindow?`, the type of the main window becomes double optional, it is really awkward.

Answer (score 1):

That's because adding `UIMainStoryboardFile` key into the app's .plist file (which is added by default) is the reason of instantiation the window.

[image]

`window` rootViewController will contains the initial view controller of the storyboard and it will be visible on the screen.

**Test it!**

*can we let the `window` nil?*

try to remove `UIMainStoryboardFile` row from the .plist file of the project and try to log the `window` in `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)` method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // if your removed 'UIMainStoryboardFile' key from the plist, this should prints nil
    print(window)

    return true
}
```

Comment: Actually, I know UIMainStoryboardFile creates it (as apple document said). But without a UIWindow the app can't function at all, so what is the purpose of making it optional ?

Comment: because in some case (as mentioned in "Test it!" section in the answer), key might not be exists, so in this case window will be nil and all you will see is a black screen

Comment: I saw your points but you seem not get mine, e.g. who will make a black screen app that makes the app not function at all ?

Comment: I think I got it... Apple says: "A UIWindow object provides the backdrop for your app’s user interface and provides important event-handling behaviors",  which means that the window is a layer that added on top of the black screen, [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow).

Answer (score 1):

I raised this question to apple engineer and following was his answer,

"An example would be initializer functions on any custom class that is assigned to one of the objects in your storyboard.  Initializer functions are run before any other method on that class is called (including -initWithCoder:, which is called on during storyboard loading).  They would run while to storyboard is being loaded but before the window object is created and assigned to the application delegate.  An initializer function could obtain a reference to the application delegate and attempt to read its window."